# react js application not starting

Tags: reactjs

I have created react application by using create-react-app command, but the application is not getting started, the exception is

```
`Client\web_client\node_modules\.bin\' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:983
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'E:\react-scripts\bin\react-scripts.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:980:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:862:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! web_client@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the web_client@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Ravi\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-04-28T07_24_51_252Z-debug.log`
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, if you have this problem, it might mean that npm didn't properly install the package. Can you verify node_modules/.bin/react-scripts exists? If not, run rm -rf node_modules and npm install and then try again.

So you need to run npm install in the project folder after cloning. After that, other commands will work too.